# Google+ API. Поле circledByCount отображается не всегда

Tags: google-plus

Когда по запросу [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) пытаюсь получить `circlesByCount`, у меня это получается не всегда. К примеру, запросы к [Gina Trapani](https://plus.google.com/+GinaTrapani) и [Leo Laporte](https://plus.google.com/+LeoLaporte) не дают получить их число подписчиков, а запросы к [Kevin Rose](https://plus.google.com/+KevinRose) и [Matt Cutts](https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts) дают. При этом у них всех на страницах можно увидеть число подписчиков. Почему так происходит? Какие настройки нужно выставить для такого результата / для предотвращения такого результата?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В настройках Google+ есть переключатель в разделе `Настройки -> Профиль -> [Показывать тех, кто добавил меня в круги]`. У тех людей, у которых `circlesByCount` не выводится при API запросе, этот переключатель в неактивном состоянии.